# How much gain I am getting and with the 2 stage transistor amplifier attached with a Global NFB

Tags: transistors, circuit-analysis, gain, low-pass, bandwidth

[image]

This is just a direct manual solving directly subtituting values in a formula with disregard to temp etc.

Sorry for the incomplete information here are the goals of this:

"gain of 100≤Av≤130 and a frequency range of 1-10 kHz":
is fine and that it must cover at least the frequency range of 1kHz≤f≤10kHz
Vcc = 15V ,
RL = 1kΩ,
Output swing 6V pk-pk,
Max input current of 10 uA

[image]

Ch 2 is the input and Ch1 is the output

Gain = 6.06/60.9mv = 99.507 ≈ 100

How do I increased this gain to my goal one? While considering the other goals.

Comment: You should check out the design in a simulator. They are free, reliable and do a good job. This would then produce "results" that you can analyse. Not sure why your question refers to "results"?

Comment: We can't tell you whether the circuit is "correct" unless you tell us what the target specifications and requirements are.

Comment: Sorry, I've made a mistake at computing the gains of each stage

Comment: What components are responsible for setting gain, can you identify them? How might changing their values affect the result?

Comment: First;y the Vcc, Input signal, and the rest is the resistors.

Comment: (An updated version of this question has been posted by the OP [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/688254/bjt-2-stage-amplifier-with-global-nfb), instead of updating this one. In order to avoid having multiple overlapping questions, which could lead to updates going into either, leaving the other one "orphaned", I'm closing this one as a duplicate of the new one.)

Comment: @SamGibson Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

> Is my results correct and accurate?.

Don't know really. Here is what I get. Made with [microcap v12](https://archive.org/details/mc12cd_202110).

Frequency AC Analysis
[image]

Input impedance
[image]

Maxi linear circuit, input volume 50 mVpeak
[image]