# BJT 2 Stage Amplifier with Global NFB

Tags: transistors, circuit-analysis, amplifier, circuit-design, breadboard

I am a designing a transistor amplifier that will have a gain of 100-130 and output-swing of 6Vpk-pk, and frequency range of 1kHz-10kHz.

I am at lost how in the simulation my circuit work with the desired outcome

[image]

[image]

But when I constructed the circuit in a breadboard and measured it values.

[image]

[image]

It is not producing the same desired result as in the simulation. Please enlighten me on the mistake I've made.

Updated Schem:

[image]

[image]

Marked up:

[image]

Comment: A decoupling capacitor should be used, anyway.

Comment: Start [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rwRtc.jpg). Explain to me which resistor and which capacitor these represent in the schematic. Looks to me like (+) goes to the resistor and the other end of that resistor goes to a capacitor whose other end goes to ground. The midpoint goes elsewhere with a grey jumper. But I don't want to look there until you explain these two to me.

Comment: I'd never trust the connection quality on a breadboard. Something could be floating or the connection may have introduced an extra resistance which may cause distortion.

Comment: @periblepsis I've putted values and the + of the cap. Please see through it. It is the mirror of the schem

Comment: Not sure where C2 is wired on the breadboard. Something seems to be hanging loose. What are the other waveforms, where is it dissappearing, or distorting? Are bias voltages correct?

Comment: @TimWilliams C2 and Rload are wired together to the osciloscope (Vo)

Comment: @Lumiere I'm still not sure what those two parts represent on the schematic. Can you specify specific part numbers from the schematic for those two?

Comment: @periblepsis The 2 parts you encircled is the bypassed resistor on stage 2 120 ohms and 100uF

Comment: Oh. Designators changed between versions. I was looking at the wrong one, I meant C8.

Comment: C8 is the capacitor that connects the collector of the 1st stage to the 2nd stage. Vo of stage 1 is Vi of Stage 2

Comment: Be aware that the 120 Ohm is wired to the + in the first breadboard version ... and to the - in the second breadboard version (which is ok).

Comment: What type of transistors did you use on the breadboard?  Also, can you measure the DC voltage at the Q1 base, emitter, and collector? And repeats the same measurement for Q2. Because for me your pictures are too small.

Comment: The fairly high 184kHz frequency of the oscillation indicates capacitive-coupling between the breadboard's many rows of contacts and the long wires all over the place. Bury the breadboard and use a compact pcb instead.

Comment: The negative electrode of C8 seams to be connected nowhere, does not reach the base of Q3.

Comment: @Audioguru We are now instead soldering it to a pcb to try and test it again.

Comment: @Jens Thanks for that observation I'll look it up again

Comment: @G36 We use 2N3904 as seen on the schematic

Comment: @tobalt Is it because my circuit only supports 50mvpk?. How can I increase it to 60Mvpk?

Comment: Is it because of the polarity of the capacitor it is getting distorted. I've placed the transistor that way because on the simulation of multisim some blow up. because of the exceeding voltage.

Comment: @Lumiere - Hi, This question overlaps *a lot* with your [previous question](/q/688006) - in fact you just asked the same question in a comment there, as you've asked in a comment here. The overlap is so big (schematic & scope trace is the same in both) that one needs to be closed, to avoid someone wasting time analysing one question, when that has already been done in the other question. Which one do you want to keep "open" and I'll close the other one. Thanks.

Comment: @SamGibson Please keep this question open and sorry for overlapping questions.

Comment: @Lumiere - Hi, Re: "*Please keep this question open*" OK, I've closed the previous one as a duplicate of this one. This looks like the 4th question that you've asked on this project / assignment / whatever it is. This reduces any chance of future readers being able to get value from those previous partial or outdated questions. Please make this your last question on this topic, so that the troubleshooting effort being given by other site members *here* doesn't get lost. Thanks.  (FYI long comment threads are discouraged here, so don't be surprised if we move comments to a chatroom soon.)